# Dividing multiple pandas dataframes by a scalar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several dataframes that I would like to divide by a scalar. Applying the operation to a single data frame at a time successfully changes the dataframes, but trying to write a for loop to do the same thing results in no change in the dataframes. Why is this? How could I write the following loop to change the dataframes?

```
# List of dataframes
dflist = [df1,df2,df3]

for i in dflist:
    i = i/1000 # This loop does not affect the dataframes

df1=df1/1000 
df2=df2/1000
df3=df3/1000 # These commands do affect the dataframes
```

Comment: All columns in the dataframes are numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a way to do division in place. As far as I know, pandas doesn't support that directly, but there's a way around that - assign to all the columns instead of to the dataframe.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0, 50).reshape(10, 5))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(50, 100).reshape(10, 5))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100, 150).reshape(10, 5))

df_list = [df1, df2, df3]

for df in df_list: 
    df[df.columns] = df[df.columns] / 10
```

if you `print(df1)`, you'll get:

```
     0    1    2    3    4
0  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4
1  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9
2  1.0  1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4
3  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9
4  2.0  2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4
5  2.5  2.6  2.7  2.8  2.9
6  3.0  3.1  3.2  3.3  3.4
7  3.5  3.6  3.7  3.8  3.9
8  4.0  4.1  4.2  4.3  4.4
9  4.5  4.6  4.7  4.8  4.9
```

### Note about in-place vs. not in-place operations

Per a question in the comments, I'll try to explain what I mean by an in-place operation. Fundamentally, an in-place operation changes the object itself. A non in-place operation creates a new object. This is demonstrated by the code below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0, 6).reshape(3, 2))
print(df1) => results in 
   0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5

print(id(df1))
4880614608 ==> this is the id (address) of the original df1

df1 = df1 / 10 ==> this produces a __new__ dataframe. 
print(id(df1))
==> 4880613520 # note that this id is different than the previous one. 


df1[df1.columns] = df1[df1.columns] * 100
print(df1) ==> this updates df1, and it now contains: 
      0     1
0   0.0  10.0
1  20.0  30.0
2  40.0  50.0

print(id(df1)) ==> The id / address of df _did_ _not_ change: 
4880613520
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Not sure why you say pandas doesn't support division in place when changing a dataframe using e.g. df = df/10 works. It also seems odd that division in place works on columns but not on whole dataframes. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: I added an explanation about in-place vs not in place changes. see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
dflist = [df1, df2, df3] 
[*map(lambda x: x/1000,  dflist)]
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't update the dataframes, but I will look into the asterisk unpacking operator - that sounds like it might be the right track.

Comment: @CarloPalazzi `dflist = [*map(lambda x: x/1000,  dflist)]`

Answer (score 1):

you could be explicit

```
df1, df2, df3 = [frame/1000 for frame in dflist]
```

the dataframes in `dflist` lose access to the variable names, and refer directly to the values. reassigning the variable names after the list comprehension gets the results we expect. Hopefully, the explanation helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in `for` loop implementation you are updating `i` and not the element of list itself. Changing the `for` loop to following should work:

```
dflist = [df1,df2,df3]

for i in range(len(dflist)):
    dflist[i] = dflist[i]/1000
```

Though this will still not update `dfi` as it will replace the elements of list with new elements. Another way would be following:

```
df1, df2, df3 = [df/1000 for df in [df1,df2,df3]]
```

Comment: Hi Abhinav, thanks for the suggestion! As you say though, this does not update the original dataframes themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for df in df_list:
    # Apply divide only on the numeric columns.
    columns = df.select_dtypes("number").columns
    df[columns] = df[columns] / 1000
```